Replacing multiple overlapping substrings in a string
I have a string in an HTML document.
astring = "R=500 mm, φ=180°, Z=599 mm von TL Boden oben. Unterliegende Schale: Boden oben."

I want to replace substrings of astring to make links. For this I have a list of dicts like
lst = [{'id': 'coordinate_systems', 'linktext': 'TL Boden oben'},
       {'id': 'PartID_1', 'linktext': 'Boden oben'}]

with the linktext field being the values to be found in astring. I want to add the href tags by simple substitution, something along the lines
astring.replace(linktext, '<a href="#{}">{}</a>'.format(_id, linktext))

by iterating over lst and doing the substitutions in each line. The naive implementation is a double loop, that is, each line of the HTML document is checked against each element of lst and substitutions are made.
And this yields incorrect results, e.g. the substring 'TL Boden oben' is replaced first
'TL Boden oben' -> '<a href="#coordinate_systems">TL Boden oben</a>'

which is OK, but then but then the 'Boden oben' inside is replaced again yielding
'Boden oben' -> '<a href="#coordinate_systems">TL <a href="#PartID_1">Boden oben</a></a>'

which is not OK anymore I needed 'TL Boden oben' and 'Boden oben' dealt with separately:
"R=500 mm, φ=180°, Z=599 mm von <a href="#coordinate_systems">TL Boden oben</a>. Unterliegende Schale: <a href="#PartID_1">Boden oben</a>."

The linktext fields are user defined, so arbitrary. These may be distinct or overlapping, that is, I can not simply do the substitutions the naivbe way, as shown before. I have no a priori knowledge how the linktext fields overlap.
I found and implemented a solution that checks if astring contains more than one linktext. If so, it simply splits astring to sentences and does the substitution on a sentence level; this is OK as it is very unlikely that overlapping linktexts will be in the same sentence (see example above).
But it is not the robust solution I'm after.
How could this problem be attacked?
EDIT:
By the answer of @Nick the outer loop was eliminated and replacements are done by regex substitutions. The inner loop is kept as not all occurancies of the links are to be substrituted, e.g. an id tag should not link to itself.
Lines, where no substitution should occur contain the substring 'nolink'. My strategy is to loop over the lines, do the substitution if 'nolink' is not a substring in the line, otherwise replace 'nolink' with ''.
Part of the original content (it is generated using jinja2), before substitution:
'<table class="table w-auto table-hover table-sm">\n'
    '<thead>\n'
        '<tr>\n'
            '<th colspan="2" scope="col" id="PartID_1">Boden obennolink</th>\n'
        '</tr>\n'
    '</thead>\n'
    '<tbody>\n'
        '<tr>\n'
            '<td>Halbkugelbodennolink</td>\n'
            '<td>Position Z = 6000.0 mm. Bordhöhe 50.0 mm. Wanddicke s = 15 mm MW. Werkstoff 1.4541, Blech.</td>\n'
        '</tr>\n'
    '</tbody>\n'
'</table>\n'

'<table class="table w-auto table-hover table-sm">\n'
    '<thead>\n'
        '<tr>\n'
            '<th colspan="2" scope="col" id="PartID_14">N02nolink</th>\n'
        '</tr>\n'
    '</thead>\n'
    '<tbody>\n'
        '<tr>\n'
            '<td>Positionnolink</td>\n'
            '<td>R=500 mm, φ=180°, Z=599 mm von TL Boden oben. Unterliegende Schale: Boden oben. Ausrichtung: normal.</td>\n'
        '</tr>\n'
        '<tr>\n'
            '<td>Zargenolink</td>\n'
            '<td>168.3 mm x 5.60 mm NW (5.20 mm MW). Werkstoff 1.4571, Blech.</td>\n'
        '</tr>\n'
    '</tbody>\n'
'</table>\n'


It sounds like you are doing too much at once. Perhaps judicious use of map or a temporary
data structure (rather than double looping) would fix things.

@G.Cito Could you elaborate how map would help here? I gave it some thought but I always ended up with the problem having a line/sentence with two substrings to be replaced by two overlapping strings. In a sense my solution to take sentences instead of full lines is doing less.

You can solve this problem using a regex replacement for all link patterns at the same time, as that will not replace previously replaced text. The key is to ensure that the linktext values are sorted by length descending; that way TL Boden oben will not be mistakenly replaced by the link for Boden oben. To simplify replacement, we make a map from linktext to the resultant link text. For example:
astring = "R=500 mm, φ=180°, Z=599 mm von TL Boden oben. Unterliegende Schale: Boden oben."
lst = [{'id': 'coordinate_systems', 'linktext': 'TL Boden oben'},
       {'id': 'PartID_1', 'linktext': 'Boden oben'}]

links = { l['linktext'] : f'''<a href="#{l['id']}">{l['linktext']}</a>''' for l in lst }
# {
#   'TL Boden oben': '<a href="#coordinate_systems">TL Boden oben</a>',
#   'Boden oben': '<a href="#PartID_1">Boden oben</a>'
# }

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(links.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)))
# re.compile('TL Boden oben|Boden oben')

out = pattern.sub(lambda m:links[m[0]], astring)

Output:
'R=500 mm, φ=180°, Z=599 mm von <a href="#coordinate_systems">TL Boden oben</a>. Unterliegende Schale: <a href="#PartID_1">Boden oben</a>.'


Perfect. It omits the outer loop; I'll still have to do it line by line as in some lines the text is not replaced (e.g. the id tags should not link to themselves). As a bonus, TIL about regex replacement, something that went below my radar until now.

@jake77 if you want to modify your question with some data that's causing an issue, I'd be surprised if that couldn't be resolved without line by line processing.

I added a part of the unprocessed data. Any insight is highly appreciated.

Which part is the part you don't want to replace?

In all lines that contain "nolink" should only have "nolink" removed, no substitutions in these.

Perhaps pattern = re.compile('(' + '|'.join(sorted(links.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)) + ')(nolink)?'); pattern.sub(lambda m:m.group(1) if m.group(2) else links[m[0]], astring)

I didn't check this; I'll stick to the previous solution. Speed is not an issue and I'll favour doing something simpler multiple times in this case. Thank you for the effort though!
